# Interleaving in Viennot's Heaps models?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, ordered-groups, topological-semigroups-and-monoids

I am looking for past results on interleaving of heaps (in the sense of Viennot).  For a very simplified example, suppose I have two pieces, (b1 a1 b1), and (b2 c2 b2), where the letter represents a resource used and the number represents which piece is being considered.  In the classical heaps-of-pieces work by Viennot, the stack of pieces would result in a stack of one on top of the other to give (b1 a1 b1 b2 c2 b2), with height of six pieces.  However, an interleaving would give (b1 (a1||b2) (b1 || c2) b2), which would be a height of only four pieces (the "||" notation is meant to indicate simultaneous operations on different resources).   Another example would be repeatedly stacking a single piece that is reentrant:  (a3, b3, a3).   My goal is to find the minimal stacking, considering multiple possible interleavings.

I am not tied to the "heaps-of-pieces" formalism.  I am open to using Cartier-Foata monoids, Mazurkiewicz' Theory of Traces, max-plus, timed Petri Nets, or any other formalism that would help me in analyzing such interleaved traces.  I am sure there are many applications that would have motivated research on such things before, but perhaps I am just not searching in the right directions with the right keywords.

Any guidance you could provide would be very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: "minimal stacking" should have been "a minimum height stacking of pieces".  It is assumed each element of each piece has a given height, thus each piece has a height, but interleaving of pieces may result in a total height less than the sum of all the pieces.  Thanks.